# PHP Smarty money_format and a non double string

Tags: php, smarty

PHP Smarty keeps complaining since my variable money isn't a double that I cant use `money_format` on it, now I am trying to convert `$money` into a double, how do I do that?

```
$money = 100;
$money|string_format:"01.2f"|money_format:"%(#10n"
```

Comment: do you have the "money_format()" plugin installed?

Comment: Would be better if you give some samples of the string you want to convert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the value to a double or add `0.0` to it to convert the type as well.

```
$money = (double)$money;
// or 
$money += 0.0; // now float
```

`sprintf` or `string_format` will still result in the value being a string even though it appears to be a double.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$money = 100.0;
$money|money_format:"%(#10n"
```